# How can I get an object to swing from a hinge faster?

Tags: physics, eevee-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I have an object that I want to swing like a pendulum and come to a halt rather quickly. I have it swinging the way I want, it is just going really slow and would take probably 3000 frames to finally stop moving. I Tried increasing the mass of the object but that did nothing. Gravity and all world settings are at default. I am using Blender 2.8 Eevee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in the rigid body world settings you can increase the speed which solved my problem